# Attempting to Connect my Kinect to Mac and code in Greenfoot Environment

Tags: java, macos, terminal, kinect, greenfoot

Running: `Mac OS X 10.8.5`

I'm following the step by step instructions on the Greenfoot website:
http://www.greenfoot.org/doc/kinect/macos.html

I've dealt with all the run arounds with installing Macports for **OSX 10.8**, and finally installed 'boost', but for the final part, at the bottom of the site I attempt to type the code in terminal at the proper directory to configure it:

```
./configure --with-boost=/opt/local/include --with-wx-config=/opt/local/bin/wx-config --with-wx-prefix=/opt/local
```

This is what it gives me and stops at this certain point. It goes through all it's configuring and stops here:

```
checking for the Boost thread library... no
configure: error: cannot find the flags to link with Boost thread
```

I've also instead tried to install boost **1.49** instead of boost **1.50**(the latest) but no luck there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Same error on Mac OS X 10.9 - from the m4/boost.m4 file from the kinectserver-1.2 directory:

Now let's try to find the library.  The algorithm is as follows: first look
for a given library name according to the user's PREFERRED-RT-OPT.  For each
library name, we prefer to use the ones that carry the tag (toolset name).
Each library is searched through the various standard paths were Boost is
usually installed.  If we can't find the standard variants, we try to
enforce -mt (for instance on MacOSX, libboost_threads.dylib doesn't exist
but there's -obviously- libboost_threads-mt.dylib).

So if there's a convenient way to tweak the source to point to "libboost_threads-mt.dylib" as the target for the "checking for the Boost thread library..." step, that would appear to be the ticket - still looking at what to tweak to accomplish this, though.